# How to pass same taxonomy from one view to another view

Tags: nodes, media

I am using nodegallery, node gallery jcarousel modules to create an image gallery.

I added taxonomy to gallery, when i click the image in gallery it will display the image with jcarousel, but taxonomy is not enabled to jcarousel, it showing all the images of the gallery.

please advice me to enable the same taxonomy to jcarousel also.

thnx.